# MPM implicit integration

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerics, calculus, particle-in-cell

## Setup

I am having a hard time translating the formulas in the 2016 MPM course from siggraph into algorithmic computations.

In particular we have equations 200 and 201

$$h(v^{n+1}) = Mv^{n+1} - \Delta t f(x^n + \Delta t v^{n+1}) - Mv^n = 0$$
$$v^{i+1} = v^i - \bigg(\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}(v^i) \bigg)^{-1}h(v^i)$$

I understand the first is implicit Euler and the second is newton's method to find a suitable approximation for the next stages velocity.

$M$ is a diagonal matrix containing the mass of grid cell $i$, $v^{k}$ are the velocities at the center of each grid cell. $h$ is the conservation of momentum equation.

## General question

What I want to do is translate these two paragraphs into pseudocode of what I must tell a computer to do. i.e. I know I need to make a sparse linear system of equations which I must then solve and the solution of that sparse system will be the new velocities at grid cell centers for the next stage. But that is much too general still, I am not clear as to what specific values should be inserted into the sparse matrix.

## Specific questions

- What is $\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}$? i.e. do I take derivatives with respect to each instance of v regardless of the superscript? Or do I only take it with respect to $v^{n+1}$. Notation here isn;t clear to me since I cannot symbol match directly.
- What is $x^n$? It would seem to me that $x$ here represents position, but grid cell positions don't change should that not be a constant?
- Can you avoid solving the full linear system directly and instead solve for things locally? Like not make the full matrix but rather query your cell neighbourhood and solve for your next velocity purely from your immediate environment.